# POST single file in Python

Tags: python, post, python-2.7, python-requests

Is there an easy way to upload single file using Python?
I know about `requests`, but it POST a dict of files containing a single file, so we have a little problem receiving that one file on the other end.

Currently code sending that file is:

```
def sendFileToWebService(filename, subpage):
    error = None
    files = {'file': open(filename, 'rb')}
    try:
        response = requests.post(WEBSERVICE_IP + subpage, files=files)
        data = json.load(response)
(...)
```

And the problem is that `requests` sends each file in a

```
--7163947ad8b44c91adaddbd22414aff8
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="filename.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain


<beggining of file content>
(...)
<end of file content>
--7163947ad8b44c91adaddbd22414aff8--
```

I suppose that's a package for a file. Is there a way to send file "clear"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `data` parameter to requests, not the `files` parameter:

```
def sendFileToWebService(filename, subpage):
    error = None
    try:
        response = requests.post(WEBSERVICE_IP + subpage,
                                 data=open(filename, 'rb'))
        data = json.load(response)
(...)
```

This will cause the file's contents to be placed in the body of the HTTP request. Specifying the `files` parameter triggers requests to switch to `multipart/form-data`.